# Add default method before calling onMessage if MessageListener of Spring Amqp

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to add some default functionality which will pick on some value from Message header in Spring Amqp before calling onMessage functionaity of implementing class .

Eg

```
class TestListener implements MessageListerner {

public void onMessage(Message message){
// some logic 
   }
}
```

From above example i need to call some customized functionality using Message object before  onMessage is called.

Is there any elegant way to achieve the same in SpringAmqp

Comment: I don't understand the question, or maybe the reason behind... If you want to change the message before receiving it, do that before you send it. Or maybe you just want to use something like headers exchange?

Comment: The requirement is to perform any business operation at the listener side before Message gets onMessage. Eg. From producer side  set the value in message header say thread name = t1 , on the Listener side , I will retrieve that value and perform any generic operation on that t1 for other message the value of threadname can be t2 etc.

Comment: But `onMessage` is called only when message is received (or I'm missing something)?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a simple wrapper class around your listener.

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // process
    myListener.onMessage(message)
}
```

Or, the listener container has a property `afterReceivePostProcessors` for exactly this reason...

```
/**
 * Set {@link MessagePostProcessor}s that will be applied after message reception, before
 * invoking the {@link MessageListener}. Often used to decompress data.  Processors are invoked in order,
 * depending on {@code PriorityOrder}, {@code Order} and finally unordered.
 * @param afterReceivePostProcessors the post processor.
 * @since 1.4.2
 */
public void setAfterReceivePostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor... afterReceivePostProcessors) { ... }
```